Show text names of small roads with cartocss
I'm using cartocss to render map with TileMill and Mapnik. Currently, text names of certain small roads appear only at a certain zoom level, the 18th or the 19th. I would like to force every roads text names to appear even if they overalp each-others.
I set text-allow-overlap: true;, but I can get the small roads text names appear only by changing the text-size to super small, and I don't want this. Anyone can explain me how does the rendering algorithm choose to show or to not show the roads-text-names labels, and how to control it ?

After many tries, I realised that the text-wrap options can be changed for that. The text length has to reach a certain width before wrapping.

I can reduce the text-wrap-width so that the text wrap even if it's width is small
-I can set the text-wrap-before option  to true, so that the text doesn't need to reach the width to wrap.

